# Optimizing a specific family of functions via gradient descent

Tags: optimization, algorithms, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose $E \subset \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d\;:\; \|x\|_2 \leq 1 \}$ for  integer $d\geq 1$ is a compact set andlet $f:E \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function which satisfies the following properties:

1. there exist $0<a<b$ and $z \in \partial E$ (i.e., the boundary of $E$)  such that $$a \|x-z\|_2 \leq f(x) - f(z) \leq b \|x-z\|_2, \quad \forall x \in E. $$
2. $z$ is the unique minimizer of $f$ in $E$, and there are no other local minima in $E$.

With this information provided, if we do gradient descent, i.e., starting with some arbitrary $x_0 \in E$, we use the update rule $x_{t+1} = x_t - s_t \nabla f(x_t)$ for $t \geq 0$; does it follow that the sequence $\{x_t\;:\; t \geq 0\}$ converges to the unique optimizer $z$?

I am not really sure how to proceed towards this since the function is not convex. Also because the optimizer is known to lie on the boundary, so it doesn't really suffice to show convergence to a stationary point.

Comment: Note that the second properties is a direct consequence of the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct an example to show that $x_t$ will not converge to $z$.

Indeed, we choose:
$E=[0,1]\subset \mathbb R^1$. Choose $f: E \rightarrow E$ continuously differentiable such that

- $f(0)=0$
- $ax\leq f(x) \leq bx$ for all $x \in E$
- $f$ has a local minimizer at $0<\hat x<1$

This function $f$ satisfies your properties.

Starting from $x_0>\hat x$, you will arrive at $\hat x$, while the global minimizer is $z=0$.

Comment: Thanks. you are right, but I actually want to study the case where $z$ is the only minimizer, i.e., there are no other local minima in $E$. I will update the question to clarify this.

Comment: @panini in such cases, let us again consider above setting and replace the third condition by the following one,
**$f$ has a local maxima at $0<\hat x<1$**
then, starting from $x_0>\hat x$, you will arrive at $1$ not $0$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.